# How do I change the cell's color comparing the value of other cell

Tags: excel

I am trying this =IF B1 > A1 then colour B1 GREEN ELSE colour B1 Red , but is not working.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: because i want to use this function in more than 100 cells. so if i use the IF function, it will be easier for me to copy this to other cells too

Comment: Conditional formatting can be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting Some good examples can be found [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat03.html)

Answer (score 1):

first I'm assuming you're using conditional formatting.

format to formula =if(logictest,valueiftrue,valueif fase)
if(b1 > a1,TRUE,FALSE)

do two seperate formulas one for red and one for green.

for example conditional formatting -> formula -> =IF(A1 fill ->Green"

and create a second rule for red if it's false

edits: conditional formatting will copy...